# How to tell someone that he is in the X% best players in a leaderboard?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, expression-choice

I'm working on a game/web app. I display a leaderboard to the players with their rank and their score.

I'd also like to display the "part" of best players they are in percentage (e. g. if there are 200 scores in the leaderboard and the player is rank 20 then he is in the best 10% players).

I'm not native-English speaker and  don't how to tell this to the player. It should be a small sentence. I was thinking about things like:

- Top XX% players
- You're in the top XX% players
- You're in the best XX% players

I don't know what is "correct" and the most understandable. Could you help me to find something clear?

Answer (score 1):

When I click on my profile, stackexchange tells me this:

> top 0.46% this month

If you don't have a time interval try

> top XX% of all time

If you insist on 'players' add an 'of'.

> Top XX% of players.

Comment: CandiedOrange's last suggestion is probably what you're looking for, but I feel I should mention percentile: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/percentile